# MYSQL DATETIME: using slashes instead of of dahses

Tags: mysql, datetime

quick question. In the DATETIME column in a MYSQL table, the format is, YYYY-MM-DD. So If i put insert today's date, as 2014-01-09, MYSQL will understand... But will it understand if i insert data like this?

YYYY/MM/DD or 2014/01/09

Comment: See: MySQL `STR_TO_DATE` function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: Have you tried to insert a row & see what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html):

> MySQL permits a “relaxed” format for values specified as strings, in which any punctuation character may be used as the delimiter between date parts or time parts.

So it would seem the answer is, yes.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> select date('2016/06/16');
+--------------------+
| date('2016/06/16') |
+--------------------+
| 2016-06-16         |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: While code often speaks for itself, answers that only contain code and have no textual explanation, get flagged for the review queues. You can avoid this by adding a sentence or two of explanation.